# plotting multiple lines in the same plot using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I need to draw multiple line graphs that has some grouping. My data is follows:

```
    roc_mj_cmb_t1= c(0.8115,0.8060,0.8114,0.8340,0.8789,0.8743,0.8807,0.8838,
                 0.7946,0.7904,0.8245,0.8198,0.8721,0.8686,0.8876,0.8763,
                 0.8204,0.8146,0.7982,0.8350, 0.7977,0.8021,0.8137,0.8176



)

roc_mj_lab= c(rep("Y1_uni_cmb_test1",4),rep("Y1_Joint_test1",4),
          rep("Y1_uni_cmb_test2",4),rep("Y1_Joint_test2",4),
          rep("Y1_uni_both_test1",4), rep("Y1_uni_both_test2",4))


settin=c("setting 1","setting 2","setting 3","setting 4","setting 1","setting 2","setting 3","setting 4"
         ,"setting 1","setting 2","setting 3","setting 4","setting 1","setting 2","setting 3","setting 4"
         ,"setting 1","setting 2","setting 3","setting 4","setting 1","setting 2","setting 3","setting 4")


data_mj=data.frame(settin,roc_mj_cmb_t1,roc_mj_lab)
```

Then I obtained the line plot using this code:

```
    ggplot(data=data_mj,
       aes(y=roc_mj_cmb_t1,x=settin, group=roc_mj_lab))+
  geom_line(
         aes(color=roc_mj_lab,linetype=roc_mj_lab))
+scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "blue", "red","blue", "red")
       )+ylim(0.75,0.9) +scale_linetype_manual(values=c("longdash", "solid","longdash", "solid",
                                                        "dotted","dotted"))
```

Here is my output:
[image]

In this plot, I need to draw the lines starting from "Y1_XXX_test1" with same color and "Y1_XXX_test2" with same color. The 3 plots within "Y1_XXX_test1" need to be differentiated using line type. Similar thing needs to be apply for "Y1_XXX_test2" as well.

But based on this code, I have got different colors than I specified. (Ex: lines with yellow, green and pink colors) What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Where is `"Y2"`? It's in neither your sample data nor the plot.

Comment: @r2evans Sorry. It was a typo. I just edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This trick doesn't hard-code each color/linetype, it separates the `roc_mj_lab` into the different "types" of groups, and sets linetype/color based on them. (One side-effect is that it splits the legend into two.)

```r
data_mj |>
  transform(
    middle = sub("Y[^_]*_(.*)_.*$", "\\1", roc_mj_lab),
    test = sub(".*_", "", roc_mj_lab)
  ) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = settin, y = roc_mj_cmb_t1, group = roc_mj_lab)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = test, linetype = middle)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(test1 = "blue", test2 = "red")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(Joint = "longdash", uni_cmb = "solid", uni_both = "dotted"))
```

[image: ggplot with colors and linetypes broken out]

The trick is that when you want certain things to share a color, there needs to be a variable in the data that is the same value for those. If we look at the first `transform`ation of the data above, you'll see the variables I created:

```r
data_mj |>
  transform(
    middle = sub("Y[^_]*_(.*)_.*$", "\\1", roc_mj_lab),
    test = sub(".*_", "", roc_mj_lab)
  )
#       settin roc_mj_cmb_t1        roc_mj_lab   middle  test
# 1  setting 1        0.8115  Y1_uni_cmb_test1  uni_cmb test1
# 2  setting 2        0.8060  Y1_uni_cmb_test1  uni_cmb test1
# 3  setting 3        0.8114  Y1_uni_cmb_test1  uni_cmb test1
# 4  setting 4        0.8340  Y1_uni_cmb_test1  uni_cmb test1
# 5  setting 1        0.8789    Y1_Joint_test1    Joint test1
# 6  setting 2        0.8743    Y1_Joint_test1    Joint test1
# 7  setting 3        0.8807    Y1_Joint_test1    Joint test1
# 8  setting 4        0.8838    Y1_Joint_test1    Joint test1
# 9  setting 1        0.7946  Y1_uni_cmb_test2  uni_cmb test2
# 10 setting 2        0.7904  Y1_uni_cmb_test2  uni_cmb test2
# 11 setting 3        0.8245  Y1_uni_cmb_test2  uni_cmb test2
# 12 setting 4        0.8198  Y1_uni_cmb_test2  uni_cmb test2
# 13 setting 1        0.8721    Y1_Joint_test2    Joint test2
# 14 setting 2        0.8686    Y1_Joint_test2    Joint test2
# 15 setting 3        0.8876    Y1_Joint_test2    Joint test2
# 16 setting 4        0.8763    Y1_Joint_test2    Joint test2
# 17 setting 1        0.8204 Y1_uni_both_test1 uni_both test1
# 18 setting 2        0.8146 Y1_uni_both_test1 uni_both test1
# 19 setting 3        0.7982 Y1_uni_both_test1 uni_both test1
# 20 setting 4        0.8350 Y1_uni_both_test1 uni_both test1
# 21 setting 1        0.7977 Y1_uni_both_test2 uni_both test2
# 22 setting 2        0.8021 Y1_uni_both_test2 uni_both test2
# 23 setting 3        0.8137 Y1_uni_both_test2 uni_both test2
# 24 setting 4        0.8176 Y1_uni_both_test2 uni_both test2
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]One of your "+"'s is in the wrong location.
The + in this line: "+scale_color_manual.." needs to be at the end of the previous line.
When I cleaned up as below, I got your blue and red lines.

```
ggplot(data=data_mj,aes(y=roc_mj_cmb_t1,x=settin, group=roc_mj_lab))+
  geom_line(aes(color=roc_mj_lab,linetype=roc_mj_lab)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "blue", "red","blue", "red"))+
  ylim(0.75,0.9) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("longdash", "solid","longdash", "solid","dotted","dotted"))
```

Answer (score 1):

you want this? Just bring into correct form:

```
ggplot(data=data_mj,
       aes(y=roc_mj_cmb_t1,x=settin, group=roc_mj_lab))+
  geom_line(aes(color=roc_mj_lab,linetype=roc_mj_lab), linewidth=1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "blue", "red","blue", "red")) +
  ylim(0.75,0.9) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("longdash", "solid","longdash", "solid",
                                 "dotted","dotted"))
```

[image]